# What program syncs folders on Mac OS X like SyncToy does for Windows?

Tags: macos, backup, sync

I'm looking for a program to sync folders between two Macs. I want to use a GUI and selectively sync. On windows there was SyncToy, which allowed you to set two paths, then preview what the sync would do (ie: which files / folders had changed) and then select which ones you wanted to take action on and what that action would be (rename, delete, overwrite, etc). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

On Mac so far I've tried:

- Superduper
- CCC cloner
- Chronosync
- RsyncX

So far Chronosync has come the closest but it's still not quite what I want. Is there a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try Unison, File Synchronizer:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html

I use this on my Mac at home and SyncToy on the Windows box at the office, they work together quite well.

Answer (score 0):

[dropbox](http://db.tt/ckdrBew) is indispensable to me, but doesn't have the preview capability that you're looking for.

[Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) is a very nice file, well polished file transfer utility (ftp/sftp/Amazon S3/etc) that can do file preview and has a sync wizard might meet your needs.  You can add rules to include/exclude files and simulate the sync to see what will get transfered.

Comment: Syncing a few files between machines, yes. The poster's programs all run on a single machine. He also specifically asks for preview of actions.

Comment: Dropbox can handle up to 100GB (actually more but those are the easy to get plans), so it's not just a few files.  I did miss the requirement to preview actions though; you're correct dropbox doesn't support that.

Comment: 100GB isn't, while quite good for online storage, that much anymore for local network data transfers. But you have to take the transfer speeds (upload + download) also into account, which can be much slower than local gigabit network.

Comment: I have Dropbox installed but am looking to sync files outside of that. In this case I wanted to run a diff between the Applications I have installed on one computer and those I have on a second computer, but I also keep some plain-text type password files (outside of dropbox) that I like to sync manually. I know TrueCrype and DB are a good option for that, too. I'll see if transmit can do the comparison. Thanks!